# App Engine keeps giving error 500 on Vanilla React site

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, cloud-hosting

I'm trying to host an unedited create-react-app project to make sure I know how to do it before hosting my other projects.

I followed the tutorial on the Gcloud console and that one worked, but when I try with a github repo I just made with a basic app, it never connects to the server. I don't get any errors through the whole process and it deploys correctly, it just never connects to the server(see image of error 500).

I thought it was a port issue because when I used the web preview on port 8080 before deploying, it showed it working correctly! So I even updated the start script to:

"start": "set PORT=8080 && react-scripts start",

That also didn't work.

Can anyone help?[error 500 screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGuyb.png)

Comment: Go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project={your-app-name} to check the logs.  That will tell you the error.

Comment: As @GAEfan mentions, is a good idea to check the logs to have more details about the error message. Could you please check the logs and add some of them in the question to check what could be going on?